# Identify an instance of theatricality and analyse its significance in Lady Audley’s Secret

Tags: lady-audleys-secret, mary-elizabeth-braddon

*Lady Audley’s Secret* (1862) is a novel by Mary Elizabeth Braddon. It has been adapted for the stage several times.

However, I would like to find an instance of theatricality in the novel itself and analyse its significance.

Comment: What instances in the novel have you considered?